# SharePoint user/group role concept issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am working with SharePoint Service 3.0/SharePoint Server 2007. SharePoint has some built-in roles like contributor, visitor, designer, administrator.

I am wondering if I use Forms Authentication, how to define roles in Forms Authentication Roles in order to map the Forms Authentication roles to SharePoint built-in roles?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no automatic mapping of Forms Authentication Roles to SharePoint built-in roles (groups).

The only thing you can do to archive such a mapping is to add the Forms Authentication Roles to SharePoint built-in groups by hand or by a custom piece of code.